# A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end

Tags: typescript

There is strange error appearing `A function returning 'never' cannot have a reachable end)`, on statement `: never`

```
interface Result {
    data: string;
}
function logResult(config: Result): never {
    console.log(config.data)
}

logResult({ data: 'This is a test' });
```

I've created a [typescript playground example with code above](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Result%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20data%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20logResult(config%3A%20Result)%3A%20never%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(config.data)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AlogResult(%7B%20data%3A%20%27This%20is%20a%20test%27%20%7D)%3B)

**What I am doing wrong and why this error appears?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`never` means that the end of the function will **never** be reached. [This blog gives a good overview of its use](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/11/18/typescript-2-0-the-never-type).

In your case though, the end of your function *is* reached, it just doesn't return a value.

You want a `void` return type to indicate a lack of returned value:

```
function logResult(config: Result): void {
```

Answer (score 6):

This error happens because you are ending a function that should "return" a never type.

There are 2 cases where functions should return *never* type:

1. In an unending loop e.g a `while(true){}` type loop
2. A function that throws an error e.g `function foo(){throw new Exception('Error message')}`

So the problem is you are reaching an end in a function that shouldn't reach an end.

Comment: Just a small piece of advice for future answers: your answer is correct (as far as I can tell), but it's missing how to fix the problem. While that wasn't explicitly asked, most people appreciate a suggestion of a fix. I've found my answers are better recieved when I add at the end an alternative solution if I know of it.

Comment: Thats a great tip and I'll definitely use it in future answers. Thanks a lot for the advice!