# Why do I have to type the input as `never` in a generic function?

Tags: typescript, arguments, contravariance, generic-variance

When I want to represent a type for *some* function, an intuitive way would be to say that it accepts an `unknown` argument (let's agree that all functions accept one argument):

```
type SomeFunction = (input: unknown) => unknown
```

… however, this leads to an error: `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '<the type of the argument>'`.

But if I use `never` instead of `unknown`, everything works fine:

```
type SomeFunction = (input: never) => unknown
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/m3qJbw).*

I always thought of `never` to be the type of no value (one that I'd use to type the return value of [a function that does not have a reachable `return` path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53885183/a-function-returning-never-cannot-have-a-reachable-end)). But so does `unknown` represent anything – and thus nothing.

**What makes `never` work better than `unknown` in this case?**

Comment: Why use `unknown` at all? If you want a generic argument, use an actual generic type, or even just `any` if you don't care about the type at all (although that's not as common).

Comment: When you declare type `SomeFunction` as taking a parameter of type `unknown`, you're saying  that a `SomeFunction` doesn't care what its argument's type is. So you can't use that type for a function that *does* care about the type of its argument.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't use `any` because of these reasons: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any. Also, I can't use generics in this case. Generics are useless in cases like this: https://tsplay.dev/mLOaKN

Comment: @ruakh An argument of type `never` is also pretty much unusable, but it works fine

Comment: @Carcigenicate To balance that, here's a case where generics are useful: https://tsplay.dev/w1GBlm . The API depends on the inner type. In my case, it does not.

Comment: What is the input never can be? Does it have any sens or practical  example? Agree with @Carcigenicate, generic in your case is ok.

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela As I said, I can't use generics. Maybe my example isn't the greatest at showing that.

Comment: @NikolaiKushpela "What is the input never can be?" – that's kind of my question. I don't understand why it works

Comment: I don't see how generics wouldn't work, or how the code you linked is at all related to the question since it doesn't use `unknown` there either. I don't know the answer to this question, but I also don't see why you're using `unknown` in the first place.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Generics wouldn't break the code, but they won't add anything useful either. The first snippet (https://tsplay.dev/mLOaKN) demonstrates that. "I'm using generics" is not the default choice, the default choice is using them (or anything else) as long as they are needed. Since `Concatenator` (the entity I describe in the code snippet) can work with any value, it doesn't benefit from having a type argument. Whereas in the second snippet (https://tsplay.dev/w1GBlm) the method `Collection.add(…)` only work if the argument is of the right type, – it benefits from being a generic.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The type `{ toString(): string }` represents basically all possible JavaScript values – except `null`, `undefined` and the result of `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @Carcigenicate The code I've linked (the two snippets) aren't related to the question, they are related to your comment